# SIMPLE SLIDESHOW of favthemes to Purity III

Tags: joomla-3.x

I use [SIMPLE SLIDESHOW](http://www.favthemes.com/extensions/product/simple-responsive-slideshow-free-responsive-joomla-module.html) of FAVTHEMES with the [Purity III](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/configuration). I have a problem with the size of slideshow, is too big, It takes all screen. I think is problem of Purity, but I dont know how to change it. The web is site is the [OpenCartography](http://www.cartography.gr/OpenCartography)

Comment: Have you contacted the developer? Hopefully there is an option to fix the maximum width in the advanced settings. Otherwise you can fix it with CSS. One way of doing that would be something like this `.flexslider .slides img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 display: block;margin:0 auto;
}`

Comment: The answer from Dev's is from Doc of plugin: Being a responsive module, this Joomla! module has no fixed width. The maximum width of the module is the width of the module position containing the module and/or the width of the device used (desktop, tablet or mobile). To test the responsive behaviour of the module columns, simply adjust the width of the browser window to different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The position you have currently assigned the slideshow to is full width. Try assigning it to a different position. If I rightly remember, the position you want to try is `feature-2`.

There may also be some settings in the Template Options to change the width of the position you have currently assigned the slideshow to